# Limits: replacing a term of a function with its limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\cos x+x\sin 4x}{x^3-\sqrt{x^6-2x^5}},$$

I proceeded to multiply both numerator and denominator by $x^3+\sqrt{x^6-2x^5}$, thus obtaining:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\cos x+x\sin 4x}{x^6-x^6+2x^5}\cdot\left(\sqrt{x^6-2x^5}+x^3\right).$$

Dividing both addends of the term to the right of the multiplication sign by $x^3$, I obtain:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\cos x+x\sin 4x}{2x^5}\cdot x^3\left(\sqrt{1-2x^{-1}}+1\right).$$

Now, according to my teacher's notes, it is legit to substitute $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\left(\sqrt{1-2x^{-1}}+1\right)$ for $\sqrt{1-2x^{-1}}+1$, thus obtaining (always according to said notes):

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\cos x+x\sin 4x}{2x^5}\cdot 2x^3.$$

My question is: is this substitution always allowed or are there certain conditions to be met or to be verified? More precisely: if I substitute a variable $x$ in the expression for the value $x_0$ to which it approaches, should that be done for *all the variables* in the equation?

Comment: FYI, use `\cos` for $\cos$ and `\sin` for $\sin$.  If you want to display $\operatorname{sen}$ you need to use `\operatorname{sen}`.

Comment: The limit of a product is the product of the limits, *if they exist*. This is the property that is *silently* used here.

Comment: In short, yes. You need to be careful just substituting for part of the expression. Example: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} 1 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x} \neq \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x} = 0$